# Kill nohup process after given time

Tags: bash, nohup

I start a command via `nohup <command> &` on the server via SSH and currently, I have to manually kill the process after a given time via
`ps -ef | grep <command>
kill <pid>`

Is there a way to use some kind of timeout with a process started with `nohup` after a given time?

Best way would be a one-liner that works on Ubuntu.

Comment: `nohup timeout 10 ping google.com &`

Comment: @jeremysprofile Thanks! I would mark your answer as solved, so don't hesitate to add a answer (and not a comment)..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
nohup timeout 10 ping google.com &
```

Not really much explanation to give. `nohup x &` runs the command in the background even if the terminal is closed. `timeout y` autokills the command after y seconds. Neat.

Comment: Just did this so you get a green check